# I can't install steam-installer on 19.10

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, steam

I'm new to ubuntu and I'm trying to download steam. I tried downloading steam installer, but I get this error.

```
sudo apt-get install steam-installer

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 steam-installer : Depends: steam (= 1:1.0.0.54+repack-5ubuntu1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

steam needs a bunch of i386 packages.

```
sudo apt update
```

and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the next before:

- Download a package: `wget https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/steam.deb`
- Install it: `sudo apt install python-apt && sudo apt install ./steam.deb`
  It asks about Starting steam to configure it for current user. I click the button and input my user's password when it prompts.

Make sure, your steam source list looks as follows:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list 
deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam
deb-src [arch=amd64,i386] http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam
```

Then try installing it again using:

```
sudo apt install steam-installer
```

Comment: I still get the same message after this.

Comment: updated answer. Please, check.